# Postgresql: Logical replication and session sharing (set_config)

Tags: database, postgresql, logical-replication

I have a table "A" on "primary" database and a logical replication "B" on "secondary" db.

Is there a way to share session config parameter (set_config) between two logical replication database ?

When I create the transaction insert request on Table A I set some set_config values.

Data are well replicated on table B but my trigger function (secondary side) on it do not retrieve session config value (with current_setting)

Comment: You will have to store the value in a table rather than in a placeholder parameter.